# About Borden's relation to Fallon

Tags: plot-explanation, the-prestige

As we know that it was Borden who sends Angier to Tesla when he asks the trick behind his magic.  So, How did Borden knew that Tesla's machine could create a replica?  Did he use Tesla's machine to create a replica(Fallon) or were they real time twin brothers?

Comment: He didn't know, that's the point. He wouldn't have sent him to Tesla  anyway if he knew Tesla could build such a thing. But anyway, clear duplicate.